# Multiple progress bars visualy update only one

Tags: javascript, html

i'm working on my JavaScript skills and this is my first program trial here.
Everything was going quite well for me, but i'm stuck on this problem for about 3 days now and i guess there is something i don't get over here.

Well, diving in - i have 2 separate "Training Fields" - each has it's own "Train" button (onclick function) , "Level up" button (onclick function) and progress bar.
The problem is that the higher "Training Field" will progress the lower progress bar and not it's own.

Help will be appreciated! thx

```js
//ignore this line, it's for me for testing
document.getElementById('hideMe').style.visibility = 'hidden';

/*========================================
 Javascript for first set
========================================*/
var bodyTotal = 0;
var totalBodyCost = 0;
var bodyCost = 100;
var amountLoaded = 1;
function buyBody(){
    bodyCost = totalBodyCost + Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,bodyTotal));
    if(amountLoaded >= bodyCost){
        totalBodyCost += bodyCost;
        bodyTotal = bodyTotal + 1;
        document.getElementById('bodyTotal').innerHTML = bodyTotal;
        var finalMessage = document.getElementById('bodyFinalMessage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        amountLoaded = 0;
    };
    var nextCost = totalBodyCost + Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,bodyTotal));
    document.getElementById('bodyCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
    document.getElementById("bodyProgressBar").max = nextCost;
    bodyCost = nextCost;
    progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
};

function progressBarSim(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('bodyProgressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('bodyStatus');
  status.innerHTML = al+"/" +bodyCost;
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
 var sim = "progressBarSim("+al+")";
 
}

function trainBody(){
    progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
    if(amountLoaded < bodyCost){
    amountLoaded++;
    }else{
           var finalMessage = document.getElementById('bodyFinalMessage').style.visibility = 'visible';
   finalMessage.innerHTML = "";
    }
};
/*=============================================*/


/*========================================
 Javascript for second set
========================================*/
var mindTotal = 0;
var totalMindCost = 0;
var mindCost = 100;
var amountLoaded = 1;
function buyMind(){
    mindCost = totalMindCost + Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,mindTotal));
    if(amountLoaded >= mindCost){
        totalMindCost += mindCost;
        mindTotal = mindTotal + 1;
        document.getElementById('mindTotal').innerHTML = mindTotal;
        var finalMessage = document.getElementById('mindFinalMessage').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        amountLoaded = 0;
    };
    var nextCost = totalMindCost + Math.floor(100 * Math.pow(1.1,mindTotal));
    document.getElementById('mindCost').innerHTML = nextCost;
    document.getElementById("mindProgressBar").max = nextCost;
    mindCost = nextCost;
    progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
};

function progressBarSim(al) {
  var bar = document.getElementById('mindProgressBar');
  var status = document.getElementById('mindStatus');
  status.innerHTML = al+"/" +mindCost;
  bar.value = al;
  al++;
 var sim = "progressBarSim("+al+")";
 
}

function trainMind(){
    progressBarSim(amountLoaded);
    if(amountLoaded < mindCost){
    amountLoaded++;
    }else{
           var finalMessage = document.getElementById('mindFinalMessage').style.visibility = 'visible';
   finalMessage.innerHTML = "";
    }
};

/*=============================================*/
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="interface.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div style="float:right">
            Body Level: <span id="bodyTotal">0</span>
            <button onclick="trainBody()">Train Body</button><br>
            <progress id="bodyProgressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:200px; float:left;"></progress>
            <span id="bodyStatus" style="float:left; z-index:555; margin-left:-110px;">0/100</span>
            <button id="bodyFinalMessage" style="float:left; visibility:hidden" onclick="buyBody()">Body Level Up</button>
            <br><br>
            Mind Level: <span id="mindTotal">0</span>
            <button onclick="trainMind()">Train Mind</button><br>
            <progress id="mindProgressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:200px; float:left;"></progress>
            <span id="mindStatus" style="float:left; z-index:555; margin-left:-110px;">0/100</span>
            <button id="mindFinalMessage" style="float:left; visibility:hidden" onclick="buyMind()">Mind Level Up</button>
  
        </div>
        
        
        <div id="hideMe" style="position:absolute; top:400; left:400">
            Body Cost: <span id="bodyCost">100</span><br>
            Mind Cost: <span id="mindCost">100</span>
        </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have only one script file? Then you are reassigning variables and functions using the exact same names `amountLoaded`, `progressBarSim(al)`.

Comment: Ohh.. silly me! - I assumed changing 'id's will be enough. Thanks, it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are reassigning variables and functions using the exact same names `amountLoaded`, `progressBarSim(al)`.

Because body and mind behavior are very similar you could use a module pattern (http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html) to use the same variable and function names within their own scopes.

```
<button onclick="Body.onClick()">Body</button>
<button onclick="Mind.onClick()">Mind</button>
```

And in your script file

```
var Body = (function() {
    var me = {};

    me.onClick = function() {
        console.log("body click");
        progressBar(al);
    };

    function progressBar(al) {

    }

    return me;
})();

var Mind = (function() {
    var me = {};

    me.onClick = function() {
        console.log("mind click");
        progressBar(al);
    };

    function progressBar(al) {

    }

    return me;
})();
```

The gotcha here is you can't use `body` with the inline `onclick` since that already refers to the body element.